# How can I create dynamic action creation in tabular form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a tabular form where giving the account number in text field the account type will display into the hidden field.

I have tried using ajax call by jquery but it doesn't work

```
declare
  typ number;
begin
  for i in 1..apex_application.g_f01.count 
  loop
      select type 
      into typ 
      from mas 
      where actnum = apex_application.g_f07(i);


    htp.p( typ );
    end loop;
    exception
      when others then
        htp.p(SQLERRM);
end;
```

after giving the account number account type will return from the table mentioned.

Comment: The `g_f01` arrays are only populated if you set them in the ajax call. Show your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

First you use the variable g_f01, and then g_f**07** - is that correct? How are they filled?
I also recommend using [apex_debug](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_debug.htm#AEAPI29182)
To make sure that everything works correctly and the data is returned.

Comment: G_F01 counts the row of $rowselector which is defined by checkbox selector and g_f07 checks the account number from mas table and select the type of it.